# How to update profile picture for existing model instance?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to update a user's profile photo after they've already created their account. I'm using an abstract user model connected to a model called Person. For additional context, I have my application connected to AWS to deploy to Heroku.

I have a form, model, url and view set up but I'm sure I'm missing some piece to the puzzle.

```html
<form action="{% url 'update-photo' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table-form">
    {{ form|crispy }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg custom-bg">
    <br><br>
  </form>
```

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Person(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upload = models.FileField(default='core/static/images/default_avatar.png')
```

```
class UpdatePhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('upload',)
```

```
@login_required
def update_photo(request):
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)
    from core.forms import UpdatePhotoForm
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdatePhotoForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user.person)
        if form.is_valid():
            person = form.save(commit=False)
            person.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = UpdatePhotoForm()
    return render(request, 'core/edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
```

```
    path('update_photo/', core_views.update_photo, name='update-photo'),
```

The form submits without any error but does not actually update the user's photo. I can change the photo in the admin site but not via the form. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to fetch file field from request Object with following code:

form = UpdatePhotoForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES, instance=request.user.person)